# How to replace a string in a file selected by a multi-line regex search pattern on Unix/MacOS with command line tools

Tags: macos, awk, sed, grep, regex-group

I'm struggling to find a one-line command to replace a bundle identifier with another bundle-identifier in a text file. The (shortened example) file looks like this:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!129 &1
PlayerSettings:
  androidSupportedAspectRatio:
    Android: 1
    iPhone: 1
  androidMaxAspectRatio: 2.1
  applicationIdentifier:
    Android: de.company.JenkinsBuildTest
    Standalone: de.company.JenkinsBuildTest
    iPhone: de.company.JenkinsBuildTest
  buildNumber: {}
  AndroidBundleVersionCode: 1
  AndroidMinSdkVersion: 16
```

My former command was:

```
sed -i -e '/applicationIdentifier/{n;n;n;s/iPhone:.*/iPhone: de.newcompany.JenkinsBuildTest/;}' ProjectSettings.asset
```

I'd like to find and replace the string behind "iPhone: " after "applicationIdentifier:". I need to add that applicationIdentifier exists only once but iPhone more than once. My problem is that "iPhone: " has to be exactly after this third line break, if "Standalone: " is missing, there won't be a change in my file.

How can I achieve a robust solution with a regex pattern?

I did everything with sed, grep, awk but no success so far. My regex pattern to find the bundle identifier should be like this:

```
(applicationIdentifier:[\s\S]+?iPhone: )([^\r\n]+)
```

But how to combine that with command line tools on a MacOS (Mojave) system?

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: You should use a YAML too to manipulate YAML data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if `My problem is that "iPhone: " has to be exactly after this third line break, if "Standalone: " is missing, there won't be a change in my file.` means you only want to modify iPhone if Standlone is present or if you have a problem in your existing code where iPhone isn't getting modified when Standalone isn't present but you want it to be. I'm doing to assume the latter.

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/applicationIdentifier:/{f=1} f && sub(/iPhone:.*/,"iPhone: de.newcompany.JenkinsBuildTest"){f=0} 1' file
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!129 &1
PlayerSettings:
  androidSupportedAspectRatio:
    Android: 1
    iPhone: 1
  androidMaxAspectRatio: 2.1
  applicationIdentifier:
    Android: de.company.JenkinsBuildTest
    Standalone: de.company.JenkinsBuildTest
    iPhone: de.newcompany.JenkinsBuildTest
  buildNumber: {}
  AndroidBundleVersionCode: 1
  AndroidMinSdkVersion: 16
```

If that doesn't do exactly what you want then edit your question to provide a better example and clarify your requirements.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, awesome! Thank you! You understood that right: The presence of "Standalone: " should not matter. I just added my chained command to replace that directly in the file: file.asset > temp.asset && mv temp.asset file.asset

Comment: This answer conflicts with your comment below the question

Comment: @hek2mgl no it doesn't. There's a vast difference between trying to solve a problem with a regexp vs solving a program with a program that employs flags, functions, regexps and compound conditions as appropriate. The issue is with the approach of trying to solve a problem with a regexp, not with using regexps when appropriate in the solution to a problem.

Comment: I disagree. If I would see this awk usage in a real world project I would classify this as poor practice. Especially since yaml does not specify the order of items in a dictionary.

Comment: Are you confusing my comment for @triplee's comment?

Comment: for me they seemed related, probably I misinterpreted the intention behind yours.

Comment: I'm just trying to help someone manipulate a block of text in a better way than trying to use sed with a multi-line regexp. I don't know yaml from a hole in the wall and the question isn't tagged with yaml so I've no idea if that block of text containing the string YAML actually is valid "yaml" or not and if it is what tool you'd use to edit it and whether or not the OP would have that tool nor how you'd do so with that tool (and I don't see any yaml editor scripts getting posted). If the text is yaml and a yaml editor answer is posted and they have that tool then the OP should use it.

Comment: In an ideal world, people would write yaml files with a yaml writer, not by rendering templates or use print(). To ensure their written yaml is valid yaml. When doing so, the output order of elements is implementation depended and not standardized, in Python it would be different than Java for example. When people read this yaml, they can not use multiline regular expressions, or something else that depends on the order of items. For the above reason

Comment: ps: of course people can also write them by hand, at least yaml is intented for that. But still the order doesn't matter. Editors of the file who don't know about this extra restriction would be surprised. But it looks auto-generated anyway.

Comment: (same applies to json btw, it's a subset of the yaml standard)

Comment: I understand that a YAML writer could be the best way to manipulate that file. But it's an generated file from Unity and I never used YAML before. The manipulation of that bundle identifier is part of a Jenkins build pipeline and so the provided solution from @EdMorton is fine for me even if its not using the regular expression I was asking for. It was my fault to think, that this might be the only way. So I'm happy.

Comment: @cyx It might be fine today, but since the order of elements can change at any time, it might not work in the future. You want to change the value of the key `PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier.iPhone`, not some string after some other string.

Comment: @hek2mgl you are absolutely right. In a perfect world, I would spend more time in solving that problem. But there is a lot more to do this week, so I'm honest and lazy and keep that "dirty" solution. But if somebody can provide a one line Unix yaml command that works without the need to install custom packages to change that identifier, I wouldn't say no.

Comment: That's a fair tradeoff if you at least know about the problem. To avoid installing extra packages I would write a small tool in the language which Unity is using to write the file, those libraries must be installed. C++? Can be that Unity even comes with such a tool, but that's just speculation. There is no standard posix tool on UNIX to do it.

Comment: A python program to do the job would be only a few lines long. It's just that pyyaml isn't part of the standard distribution. If my project works with yaml, I would make pyyaml a build-time requirement and add a binary `tools/setup-build-conf.py` (or whatever) to my project. Besides that, Google reveals a few hits on general yaml editors (like jq for json). I haven't tried any of them.